# A 2D chess like map?

Tags: android, arrays, 2d

i once started to make a android game and stoped at the point where i had to find a way to make a 2D map.

A lot of you maybe know the game "Master of Orion 2"
Example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0S2RZB6-uY

The problem that i now have is that i'm not smart enoth to find a way to make a 2D chess like map that will work like the starmap that you can see on 11:00

i was thinking about a X*Y field and a code that will set some of them to solar systems (diced out so to say), while the others stay in the "unused" state and are only fields that you have to pass through.

also.. can i make a direkt way from A to B? or do i have to fly over the fields step by step?

sorry for my imperfect english, i'm not a native speaker. i'm just trying to learn some java and make make tablet usefull again, because i dont think that there is a MoO2 game out so far (i just love round based games)

Comment: I see nothing wrong in making 2D array where appropriate values means different objects. What is your problem in fact? About traveling question you can do whatever you want, your game your rules...

Answer (score 0):

My problem goes more into the direction of "how do it do it?"

So far i know that i can make it like this:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {

    int  [][] galaxy;
    galaxy = new int [8][10];
```

this would build a galaxy of 8x10 fields, while i'm now searching for the best way to get it on screen with a black background and then making some of those fields (they are state 0 amt, right?) into solar systems, by giving them a JPG that i can klick on to open the solar system (a normal list windown will do it at first) and then select the planet to build on it.

i understand that a planet is a array in the array, but so far i'm not sure how to creat them an get them on screen, so i can give them attributes

it also seems that JLabel is not working for androind and thats why i'm stucked